# For every set $X$ show that $\emptyset+ X=\emptyset X = \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For every set $X$ show that $\emptyset+ X=\emptyset X=\emptyset$.

For example, let  $X$={1,2}. Then, $\emptyset+ X=\emptyset X=\emptyset$.

My question is HOW? I did not understand this example.

Comment: HINT: Start with the definitions of the sum and product of sets.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not . . . is $X+Y$ defined as $\{n: \exists x\in X, y\in Y(n=x+y)\}$? (I suspect it is.) Try a concrete example: what is $\emptyset+\{1\}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Let $Y=\emptyset$. Then, we will show $X+Y=Y$. by the definitions, {$x+y$= $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$}={$y \in Y$}. Can you explain this step?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why not $\emptyset +${$1$}= {$1$}?

Comment: @Kahler Because $\emptyset+\{1\}$ is the set containing all distinct results of: taking an element from *the empty set* and adding it to an element from $\{1\}$. $~$ However there are no elements in the empty set, so no results can be obtained. $~\therefore~\{\}+\{1\} = \{\}$

Answer (score 4):

Let's do a concrete example. By definition (I suspect) $A+B$ is the set of $n$ such that for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, $a+b=n$.

For example, if I want to show that $3$ is an element of $\{0, 1\}+\{2, 3\}$, I need to find one element from each set which can sum to $3$. Here, one way to do it is $1$ and $2$ respectively.

Now what about $\emptyset+\{2, 3\}$? If I think $2$ is in this set, I need to find an element of $\emptyset$ and an element of $\{2, 3\}$ which add up to $2$. Do you see where the problem is?

Comment: I understood. Thanks!